# Exceeds limit error SSRS RDL file when migrating to SQL Server 2016 from 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We are migrating all of our legacy files to a new SSRS install on Windows Server 2016 using SQL Server 2016. I have checked the setting for reporting services, MaxfileSizeMb set at -1.

The RDL that is failing is 4.5 MB in size.

From all the documentation I can find there is no longer a `web.config` for SSRS in 2016 to modify or I can not find it.

I have also confirmed that all restored source databases for SSRS on the new server are set to compatibility level 130.

We are getting the following error:

> Error
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file.
>
> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.
>
> at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
> at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.` is nothing to do with the size of files on disk, it's complaining that a HTTP/HTTPS request (file upload) is too big. AFAIK SSRS still has a `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\web.config` file and you should add/edit the request limits there as you would with IIS (httpRuntime@maxRequestLength and requestLimits@maxAllowedContentLength).

Comment: Thanks so much the file structure on our VM hosting it placed it in on a different drive, but knowing it was there i was able to find it and fix it.